# seo friendly url using .htaccess css file is not loaded

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, seo

i have a url which looks like

```
https://sparkle.000webhostapp.com/movie.php?id=16
```

i want to change it as

```
https://sparkle.000webhostapp.com/movie/16
```

i have created .htaccess file as

```
   Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# redirect "/movie.php?id=xxx" to "/movie/xxx"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/movie\.php\?id=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /movie/%1? [R=301,L]

# internally rewrite "/movie/xxx" to "/movie.php?id=xxx"
RewriteRule ^movie/([0-9]+)$ /movie.php?id=$1 [L]
```

but the problem is the style file ,i.e.,css file is not loaded.
no styles are defined in the link

Comment: What does your `<link rel ...` element look like?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="homepage.css" />

Comment: if i am not using the .htaccess file. everything is ok! but after using .htaccess file link is converted but css file is not loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your CSS is referenced like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="homepage.css" />`, it will be relative to the request's path!

Initially, requests to `/movie.php?id=123` would render a page whose css was assumed to be at `/homepage.css`.

But, when you create that rewrite, the request is understood as `/movie/123`, and the css is assumed to be at `/movie/homepage.css`.

To get around this problem, begin the reference to your CSS with a `/`, so that it's always in reference to the web root.

**The updated `<link>` tag should be `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/homepage.css" />`**

You can confirm this by checking your browser's error console and looking for something like "`GET https://sparkle.000webhostapp.com/movie/homepage.css 404`"

Comment: yes !! this works now . thank you.

Comment: one thing more. changing the url will be helpful in google indexing??

Comment: I think so! https://moz.com/learn/seo/url